# mysql:5.6 docker image is executing `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` on every `nerdctl compose down; nerdctl compose up` how to limit it to first build?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, containerd, rancher-desktop, nerdctl

As mentioned above the database is being initialized on every `nerdctl compose down; nerdctl compose up`? We are trying to spin a test database with some seed data for local testing.

The following is the `Dockerfile` definition

```
FROM mysql:5.6

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE some_name
ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD 1
COPY mysql-bootstrap/*.sql* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 3306
```

The following is the `docker-compose.yml` file definition.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  database:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build: database
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

I've not mounted any volume as I wanted to use docker's internal volume management as mentioned in `Where to Store Data` section of https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

I'm using `nerdctl` provided by `rancherdesktop` on `macos`